# Opencv Error to crop the image in iPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, image-processing, opencv

I used the below code to set ROI and crop the image.

```
cv::Mat testMat = [CaptureViewController cvMatWithImage:self.storeImage];
cv::Rect roi(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
cv :: Mat image_roi;
image_roi = testMat ( roi );

self.CroppedImage = [CaptureViewController imageWithCVMat:image_roi];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.CroppedImage, self,  nil,nil);
```

But am getting the below error:

```
<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows)
```

I set break-point and tested here is where am getting the above error `image_roi = testMat ( roi );`.

But I couldnt trace the reason for this issue. Am I wrong anywhere in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone() the object.

```
image_roi = testMat(roi).clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this but maybe it will help someone else facing similar issue. The error seems to be pretty self-descriptive. 
It says that your roi (region of interest) rectangle seems to be going out of the bounds of the cv::Mat.

Make sure that the (left top x, left top y, width, height) fall within the bounds of your testMat:

```
faces[i].x = faces[i].x >= 0 ? faces[i].x : 0;
faces[i].y = faces[i].y >= 0 ? faces[i].y : 0;
faces[i].width = faces[i].x + faces[i].width > testMat.cols ? testMat.cols - faces[i].x : faces[i].width;
faces[i].height = faces[i].y + faces[i].height > testMat.rows ? testMat.rows - faces[i].y : faces[i].height;
```